# drop down select on web from macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select an option from web in a drop down.I keep on getting this error of

> "object variable not set"

and when i click on debug it brings me to the following block of code:

```vb
For Each element In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
If element.innerText = "262|Creator|0" Then
  element.Selected = True
Else
  ms = MsgBox(element.innerText)
End If
Next
```

Comment: can you share the url and the start of your code? If you step through executing line by line with F8 does the error still occur?

Comment: I was tempted to post "Set the object variable." as the answer.  Then I realized there wasn't a question.

Comment: ^^ and yes it would be helpful to re-phrase via [edit] so there is an explicit question.